# Creating an ssl connection to oracle db with Java

Tags: java, oracle, ssl, jdbc, ojdbc

I'm trying to connect to an Oracle DB using Java and SSL. For now I have the Java program on the server with the database.

I'm getting this error when I try to run it (full error in comment):

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Inbound closed before receiving peer's close_notify: possible truncation attack?, connect lapse 15 ms., Authentication lapse 0 ms.
```

This is my java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Security.addProvider(new oracle.security.pki.OraclePKIProvider());
        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=2484))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=ORCL)))"; 
        Properties props = new Properties(); 
        props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", 
                "C:\\app\\Administrator\\virtual\\product\\12.2.0\\dbhome_1\\bin\\wallets\\Administrator\\cwallet.sso"); 
        props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType","SSO"); 
        props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", 
                "C:\\app\\Administrator\\virtual\\product\\12.2.0\\dbhome_1\\bin\\wallets\\Administrator\\cwallet.sso"); 
        props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType","SSO"); 
        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
```

I added this to listener.ora and tnsnames.ora (I also tried with the sso file and just linking to the directory)

```
WALLET_LOCATION=(SOURCE=(METHOD=FILE) (METHOD_DATA=(DIRECTORY=C:\app\Administrator\virtual\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\wallets\Administrator\ewallet.p12 ))
SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION=TRUE
```

I also added this to java.security:

```
security.provider.11=oracle.security.pki.OraclePKIProvider
```

edit: I didn't realize the length limit on comments was so short. Here's the full error:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Inbound closed before receiving peer's close_notify: possible truncation attack?, connect lapse 11 ms., Authentication lapse 0 ms.
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:790)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Inbound closed before receiving peer's close_notify: possible truncation attack?, connect lapse 11 ms.
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolNIO.negotiateConnection(NSProtocolNIO.java:138)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:317)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1438)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:518)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Inbound closed before receiving peer's close_notify: possible truncation attack?
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.closeInbound(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.net.nt.SSLSocketChannel.fill(SSLSocketChannel.java:534)
    at oracle.net.nt.SSLSocketChannel.unwrap(SSLSocketChannel.java:434)
    at oracle.net.nt.SSLSocketChannel.handshake(SSLSocketChannel.java:350)
    at oracle.net.nt.SSLSocketChannel.write(SSLSocketChannel.java:238)
    at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.writeToSocketChannel(NIOPacket.java:211)
    at oracle.net.ns.NIOConnectPacket.writeToSocketChannel(NIOConnectPacket.java:232)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolNIO.negotiateConnection(NSProtocolNIO.java:108)
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: Which version of Oracle, which version of the Oracle JDBC driver, which version of Java (full versions of all please)

Comment: @Mark Oracle version: 12.2.0.1.0  OJDBC: 12.2.0.1 Java: 1.8.0_191

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue?I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 2):

Can you make sure to have oraclepki.jar, osdt_core.jar and osdt_cert.jar in the classpath? You don't need to use keystore and truststore properties. Use oracle.net.wallet_location and oracle.net.ssl_server_dn_match=true.  Check out the [blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/ssl-connection-to-oracle-db-using-jdbc%2C-tlsv12%2C-jks-or-oracle-wallets) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, I do have them in the classpath. Do you know if there's a way to set wallet_location and ssl_server_dn_match inside the java code? I'd rather avoid having to setup a script to run this if I can.

Comment: Yes, you can set those as connection properties. Check out DataSourceForJKS (https://github.com/oracle/oracle-db-examples/blob/master/java/jdbc/ConnectionSamples/DataSourceForJKS.java) for a reference